# How to create a VM using powershell and azure function

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I want to create a VM using Powershell Script on Azure.

This PowerShell script should run as Azure Function.

This Azure Function should MSI(Managed Service Identity) to create Resources.

This Azure Function should be exposed as HTTP API to hit it with some authentication parameter.

Comment: Your question is overly broad and you're unlikely to get an answer.  Consider the advice at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and perhaps get started on your own. Then come back with new specific questions you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

you can check-
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/02/24/using-powershell-modules-in-azure-functions/

Use HTTP functions and for MSI check this-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity

Thanks,
Shraddha Agrawal